# Button not works with Contact form in Visual Composer Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a button to call the Contact form 7 in a Visual Composer-powered theme. However it's not working, nothing pops up. If I instead place a link with `popup-form` class, it works. So i guess i need somehow place this class in the `<a>` tag of the button. How can I do that?

Comment: Please be more precise: Add error messages, ideas you already tried, more details in general...

Comment: There are no error messages. I have a link above the button, and it works. Please check out: http://artemdi3.bget.ru/home-3/. The link 'I'm working' does work, the red button 'I'm not working' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure wether I got you right or not. Assuming you want to add the button element from the visual composer: when you choose button in the visual composer backend there is a popup with options coming up. The last field is for the class. Please have a look at the screenshot:[image: button popup in visual composer]

This procedure results in a `button` element. If it needs to a `a` element you can make it quick and dirty by writing a js line or you can do it professional by [overriding the html output of the button shortcode](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Change+Shortcode%27s+HTML+Output) of visual composer or [adding an own shortcode to visual composer.](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Adding+Custom+Shortcode+to+Grid+Builder)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I chose quick and dirty method by adding a Javascript block and putting a jquery line that added popup class to the btn-classed link. It's really dirty as it would affect all the buttons but I have only one.